# Custom Exception issue

Tags: java, exception

I have created a custom exception class as follows

```
public class CustomException extends Exception{
// some code here
}
```

Now I have a piece of code as follows

```
File file = new File("some_file_path");
try {
    FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
} catch (CustomException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();        
}
```

But the compiler shows error **Unhandled exception type FileNotFoundException**

My point is doesn't the compiler understand I'm catching FileNotFoundException through CustomException?

Please help.

Comment: Android tag should not be included, there's no related android objects on your question Ok?

Answer (score 7):

`FileNotFoundException` is subclass of `IOException` which is subclass of Exception.

Hierarchic -

```
java.lang.Throwable
    java.lang.Exception
        java.io.IOException
            java.io.FileNotFoundException
```

And `CustomException` is subclass of `Exception` which hierarchic is -

```
java.lang.Throwable
    java.lang.Exception
        java.io.CustomException
```

It is clear `CustomException` is not in chain of Exception and it is not super class of neither `IOException` nor  `FileNotFoundException` that is why you can not catch `FileNotFoundException` with `CustomException`.

But you can catch `FileNotFoundException` with `IOException`, `Exception` and `Throwable` except `FileNotFoundException`.

Comment: Thanks Quoi. Now CustomException extends IOException but the error still exists.

Comment: you can't do that. You can only catch that exception with FileNotFoundException or IOException or Exception or Throwable.

Answer (score 2):

What compiler understands is `FileNotFoundException` and `CustomException` are two different exceptions. You need to catch both exceptions like :

```
File file = new File("some_file_path");
try {
    FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
    // do some operation
    // if some cond is not satisfied
    // throw new CustomException("Error Message");
} catch (CustomException | FileNotFoundException e) { // syntax valid if you are using java 7, otherwise write one more catch block
    e.printStackTrace();        
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`CustomException` is just different type than `FileNotFoundException`, so it's a no-go.

Essentially you can type:

```
} catch (T e) {
}
```

where `T` must be a type that is assignable from value of type `FileNotFoundException`, i.e. the same or more general (super class) type.

Comment: That's not what you wrote a minute ago, even if customException extends fnfe it won't catch

Comment: that's why I corrected it. after whole night of work one can just write something stupid at first.

Comment: But this is still not quite correct. What is T? Did you mean Exception? You have to catch fnfe or a superclass

Comment: now you're just picky. I've specified that `T` is a type. I intentionally didn't say `Exception` - *like I said* it can be any type that is assignable from `FNFE`, i.e. `T.class.isAssignableFrom(FNFE.class)` is `true`.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see the superclass part.

Answer (score 0):

This is the signature for [`FileOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream%28java.io.File%29) with `File` as parameter:

```
public FileOutputStream(File file) throws FileNotFoundException
```

`FileNotFoundException` is a [**checked exception**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exception_handling#Checked_exceptions), meaning it has to be handled explicitly (caught/thrown). You're catching `CustomException` instead of what you **must** catch/throw (in this case `FileNotFoundException`). Besides, `FileOutputStream` is of `IOException` subclass whereas `CustomException` is of `Exception` subclass. There is no-relationship between `CustomException` and `IOException` in hierarchical level.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you expect your CustomException class to catch FileNotFoundException? `FileNotFoundException Class is extended by IOEXception class (IOException is extended by Exception Class)` , your CustomException class is Extending only Exception class which is superclass of FileNotFoundException and Exception class .